# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry - After theme change

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, database, orders, onepage-checkout

After I changed my theme I am getting error messages in Magento log and also the checkout is working correctly if I use my previous theme. The other thing is it's saying `Duplicate entry '63' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID'`. I have checked the Magento database - there the increment invoice is in thousands. Could it be conflicting with an extension?

**ANY Help will be appreciated. I have already checked all other answers regarding `Integrity Constraints` on Magento and tried all the solutions but it didn't work**

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '63' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order` (`coupon_code`, `protect_code`, `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`, `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`, `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`, `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`, `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`, `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`, `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`, `customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`, `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `shipping_discount_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `weight`, `customer_dob`, `increment_id`, `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`, `customer_email`, `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_middlename`, `customer_prefix`, `customer_suffix`, `customer_taxvat`, `discount_description`, `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `remote_ip`, `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`, `x_forwarded_for`, `customer_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `total_item_count`, `customer_gender`, `hidden_tax_amount`, `base_hidden_tax_amount`, `shipping_hidden_tax_amount`, `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt`, `shipping_incl_tax`, `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `gift_message_id`, `auctaneapi_discounts`, `fee_amount`, `base_fee_amount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2018-01-23 23:17:07', '2018-01-23 23:17:07', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /home/template/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
/home/template/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
/home/template/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
/home/template/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
/home/template/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
/home/template/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_orde...', Array)
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(151): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(812): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(579): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/local/WP/OnePageCheckout/controllers/OnepageController.php(7): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): WP_OnePageCheckout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/home/template/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/home/template/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/home/template/public_html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you create new store for new theme?

Comment: yes i have install this theme for separate store... where as in my default store where my previous theme is installed.. the checkout is working correctly....

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong for your last_increment_id for this store.
There is "64" value for store id 11, should be something like 11000064.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments where as it has nothing to do with that store. The template which i set up is for store no 6 where as i have find the issue. The issue is i am adding item in cart on store 6 where as when i jump to checkout it automatically set another store in session, that's why the store id is conflicting and i am unable to create a order.

Comment: I will check it again that i am facing this situation because of this error which is auto set another store when i jump on checkout page else i will wait for correct answer.